# how to run nodeunit tests with reports on Jenkins

Tags: node.js, testing, jenkins, continuous-integration, nodeunit

Im trying to find a way to run nodeunit tests on Jenkins and sow the results.
up until now ive only found how to do it with mocha and other framework and not with nodeunit.
is there a plugin or jenkins or something that i should do ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Iv'e figured it out.
you can run the tests using:

```
nodeunit test/ --reporter junit --output ./output_dir
```

and then configure jenkins to publish those junit xmls.